# Compare values between one text file and another for matching

Tags: python

I have a text file (results.txt) that contains a list of Hashes, URLs, IPs.

Trying to:

1.extract only the URLs in the "match" value where there is also key "type":"url"

2.to compare all URLs with another local text file that contains a list of known domains(Alexa.txt).

3.If there is a match in the compare process then to delete the URL line from the results.txt file

text file example:

```
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "http://firefox.com/eiKMths", "type": "URL", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"}
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "http://amazon.com/m7GTLj59x7", "type": "URL", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"}
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "109.228.9.122", "type": "IP", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"}
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "ED9DF1625C1D981FE54490FAB7934BE36322E4C5C88A19F4C244307DF2523E52", "type": "SHA256", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"}
```

So the goal is to compare: **firefox.com** and **amazon.com** 
against the Alexa.txt . if there is a match then delete the URL line from the results.txt file.

My code is very undeveloped, quite lost...

Comment: Can you show some code of what you tried?

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. In fact there is no question in this question (other than the implicit "can you write this for me?"). See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, forget adding my code. sorry

Comment: The "JSON file" you provided is not formatted as one piece of JSON. Instead, it contains several JSON blobs seperated by newlines.  Yet your sample code is trying to parse the entire data file as one?  For starters, You would need to load *each* line as json (or fix your data file so it's one nested JSON string)

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This is rather broad with a lot of questions rather than  just 1.

For starters you need a valid JSON string e.g.

```
[{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "http://firefox.com/eiKMths", "type": "URL", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"},
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "http://amazon.com/m7GTLj59x7", "type": "URL", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"},
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "109.228.9.122", "type": "IP", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"},
{"path": "pastebin.com", "match": "ED9DF1625C1D981FE54490FAB7934BE36322E4C5C88A19F4C244307DF2523E52", "type": "SHA256", "page": 1, "file": "pastebin.com"}]
```

With this structure you can do the test on if type == URL

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\pyJSON.json') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)
print([f for f in data if f['type']=="URL"])
```

Hopefully, that moves things a long a little.